# How to get height of Popup after it is set to wrap_content?

Tags: java, android, popup

Helo,

I've got this popup:

```
    // Inflate the popup_layout.xml
    LinearLayout viewGroup = (LinearLayout) context.findViewById(R.id.popup);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.day_popup_date, viewGroup);

    layout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

    int popupWidth = width;
    final int popupHeight = height;

    // Creating the PopupWindow
    final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(context);

    popup.setContentView(layout);
    popup.setWidth(popupWidth);
    popup.setHeight(ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT);
    popup.setFocusable(false);
```

As you see, popup.setHeight(ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT); is set to wrap content.

But I want enlarge the popup to 600px if the size is smaller than 100px.

How can I do that?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it:

```
    ViewTreeObserver vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            if(layout.getMeasuredHeight()> 0){

                layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                int heightmeasured = layout.getMeasuredHeight();

                if(heightmeasured < popupHeight) {
                    popup.update(popupWidth, popupHeight);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

simply write...

```
 popup.setHeight(600);
```

Comment: But what if popups height is for example 800 after Wrap_content? Then it would shrink to 600. That's not what I want. I want to check first the height, then set it bigger if its smaller than 600.

Comment: Then write 800 replace of 600.

Comment: And how do I get the popups height after wrap_content? There are two textviews in popup, that should be displayed without condition. When I shrink to 600 it could be, that the Textviews are not displayed properly.

Comment: Then you have to increase value as compare to 600.

Comment: Hmmm... When I access System.out.println("Height: " + popup.getHeight()); it gives: Height: -2